# SQL Server - how to extract month from date?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Assuming that there is a Column for DateOfBirth as date (datatype) are how can i implement an SQL to find the birthday of people who are born only on February.

Comment: `WHERE MONTH(DateOfBirth) = 2`

Answer (score 2):

```
select DateOfBirth from MyTable where month(DateOfBirth) = 2;
```